# While committing get error by Eslint in css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, eslint, stylelint

I'm getting error while committing the code on GIT. I'm setting with ESLINT and Stylelint. I have written simple css but I'm getting error. In the first line and first column getting issue

```
2:1  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token

1 | /* Form elements style */
> 2 | .flex-wrapper {
  | ^
3 |     display: flex;
4 |     flex-wrap: wrap;
5 |     margin: 0px -20px;

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
husky > pre-commit hook failed (add --no-verify to bypass)

`/* Form elements style */
.flex-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0px -20px;
}`
```

.stylelintrc

```
    {
  "extends": "stylelint-config-recommended"
}
```

lint-staged.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  linters: {
    '**/*.+(js|jsx|md|css|yml|yaml|scss)': [
      './node_modules/.bin/eslint --fix',
      './node_modules/.bin/stylelint *.css --fix',
      './node_modules/.bin/prettier --write',
      'git add',
    ],
  },
  ignore: ['node_modules', 'package.json', 'package-lock.json'],
};
```

.eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  extends: ['airbnb', 'prettier', 'prettier/react'],
  plugins: ['markdown'],
  parser: 'babel-eslint',
  env: {
    browser: true,
    jest: true,
  },
  rules: {
    'react/button-has-type': 0,
    'react/require-default-props': 0,
    'import/named': 0,
    camelcase: 0,
    'react/destructuring-assignment': 1,
  },
};
```

Comment: Why are you running ESLint on a CSS file? Change your Git hook to only lint JS files.

Comment: This question is unclear. Did you configure stylelinting for your css files? How did you configure them?

Comment: just now I have updated @Jimmy

Comment: `'**/*.+(js|jsx|md|css|yml|yaml|scss)': [  './node_modules/.bin/eslint --fix'` again, why are you running CSS files, and SCSS, as well as YML, YAML and MD files through ESLint? *By definition* they don't contain valid JavaScript. I guess except MD which might or might not as it's simply test, but I doubt it's something you'd want linted anyway.

Comment: Thank for giving some clarification @VLAZ

Answer (score 3):

Problem with lint-staged.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
  linters: {
    '**/*.+(js|jsx|md|yml|yaml)': [
      './node_modules/.bin/eslint --fix',
      './node_modules/.bin/prettier --write',
      'git add',
    ],
    '**/*.+(css|scss)': [
      './node_modules/.bin/stylelint *.css --fix',
      './node_modules/.bin/prettier --write',
      'git add',
    ],
  },
  ignore: ['node_modules', 'package.json', 'package-lock.json'],
};
```

Now it's working fine

Comment: I had a different setup with linters, it being inside the package.json file, but I did a similar solution that helped by simply removing css/scss (and .md) files from the js/jsx part and put it in its own part and now it works, since eslint doesn't run on the unnecessary files

Comment: You can replace `./node_modules/.bin/eslint --fix` with `npx eslint --fix`. and the same for prettier.

"When executing a package, it will look for them either in the local or global path"
 - https://www.section.io/engineering-education/npm-vs-npx/